# Virus Corrupted MVC C# Project Causing Unrecognized escape sequence error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### Please Help me Fix this Strange problem !

in last few days my computer is affected by virus "Readme.eml" 
this virus affected all my Html and CsHTML files in my computer.

the virus  added new line in every cshtml file in all my project
the line is `<html><script language="JavaScript">window.open("readme.eml", null,"resizable=no,top=6000,left=6000")</script></html>`

Opened One of my Project and when ever i run the compiler states error at this line while parsing the view.

**i've done to overcome this problem ; but still no luck !**

1. Successfully Cleaned the Readme.eml virus and all its Files using multiple Anti-Viruses
2. Open One of My Projects to Recover
3. Searched the  Script code added by the virus `<html><script language="JavaScript">window.open("readme.eml", null,"resizable=no,top=6000,left=6000")</script></html>` and Replaced with empty spaces (almost 2000 lines replaced in all views)
4. Cleaned and rebuilt the project successfully
5. when i run the project **Now**  it throws  `Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence`

The Error line states `Line 1194:WriteLiteral("\\r\n");`

The Source File : `Source File: c:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\1bc13a3b\8a6f90dd\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.teskwqdt.0.cs    Line: 1194`

I Searched **WriteLiteral("\r\n");** in the project butr cant find it anywhere !

Comment: Have you deleted that file looked for similar files in temp folder?

Comment: Search for WriteLiteral("\\r\n") (double escaped r)

Comment: @RamblinRose  i've tried WriteLiteral("\\r\n") but still cant find (whole Project)

Comment: @S.Petrosov   What file you mean ? what temp folder

Comment: @MohamedNor c:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\1bc13a3b\8a6f90dd\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.teskwqdt.0.cs

Comment: @S.Petrosov i've deleted every thing in that folder but still getting the same error ; also the Virus file readme.eml is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Hours of struggling with this Problem ; finally i got the problem and solved it.

while i was trying to remove Extra lines added by the virus with Find & Replace  `<html><script language="JavaScript">window.open("readme.eml", null,"resizable=no,top=6000,left=6000")</script></html>`  i left a whitespace-like character after this line ;

[image: White Spaces after Removing the Script line]

And Finally Removing Those Characters From all views Manually Solved the Problem !